# Can we use Tab menu in Widget Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have created widget for my application and I need to add two tabs one is `Favorite` another is `Recent List`. Is there any way to use tab in widget. I searched in google but I cant any tutorials.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are exactly want. But maybe pager view with tabs is what you are you looking for? There are also some custom tab libraries you can find on githab you can use

Comment: what i want is, in widget can we add tab host? @thealeksandr

Comment: If you mean an App Widget, no. You can only use [certain Views and Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout). You could certainly emulate tabs, though, with the available components.